# date filter is not working with or without lubridate in R

Tags: r, shiny

I don't know why date filter is not working with or without lubridate. I have tried to achieve it with as.Date() function and even with lubridate but it is still not working,I have tried to get it done with data table and it is working quite well in that case,it is something wrong with plotly which is causing error here. I am not sure what i am  missing here. please could anyone guide me through this issue.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(lubridate)

total<-tibble::tribble(
         ~Order.ID, ~Order_Date, ~CustomerName,              ~State,                ~City, ~sales,
         "B-25601",  "4/5/2017",      "Bharat",           "Gujarat",          "Ahmedabad",  1275L,
         "B-25602",  "4/6/2017",       "Pearl",       "Maharashtra",               "Pune",    66L,
         "B-25603",  "4/7/2017",       "Jahan",    "Madhya Pradesh",             "Bhopal",     8L,
         "B-25604",  "4/8/2017",      "Divsha",         "Rajasthan",             "Jaipur",    80L,
         "B-25605",  "4/8/2017",     "Kasheen",       "West Bengal",            "Kolkata",   168L,
         "B-25606",  "4/9/2017",       "Hazel",         "Karnataka",          "Bangalore",   424L,
         "B-25607",  "4/9/2017",    "Sonakshi", "Jammu and Kashmir",            "Kashmir",  2617L,
         "B-25608", "4/10/2017",     "Aarushi",        "Tamil Nadu",            "Chennai",   561L,
         "B-25609", "4/11/2017",      "Jitesh",     "Uttar Pradesh",            "Lucknow",   119L,
         "B-25610", "4/12/2017",      "Yogesh",             "Bihar",              "Patna",  1355L,
         "B-25611", "4/13/2017",       "Anita",            "Kerala", "Thiruvananthapuram",    24L
         )

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "date",
                 label = 'Date range',
                 start = Sys.Date() - 28, end = Sys.Date() + 2,
                 format = "mm/dd/yyyy",
                 separator = "TO")
      )),
  dashboardBody(
  fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("state", height = 200))))

axis_titles <- . %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = ""),
    yaxis = list(title = "Sales"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  State <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State"), {
    State(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State")$x)
  })
  
  output$state <- renderPlotly({
    
     #total$Order_Date<-as.Date(total$Order_Date,format = "%m/%d/%Y")
     total$Order_Date<- mdy(total$Order_Date)
     #class(total$Order_Date)
     #  
     re_filt <- filter(total,
           between(total$Order_Date,
                   as.Date(input$date[1]) ,
                   as.Date(input$date[2])))
     
     total%>%
      count(State, wt = sales) %>%
      plot_ly(data=re_filt,x = ~State, y = ~n, source = "State") %>%
      #filter(total$Order_Date>= input$date[1] & total$Order_Date<= input$date[2]) %>% 
      axis_titles() %>% 
      layout(title = "State")
  })

}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: I beg your pardon but I didn't get what you meant by that, could you please elaborate  a little bit more. thanks for your concern though.

Comment: Never mind.  I thought Date is the issue from title.  It appears that you have other errors.  Please post (in your question) exactly what errors you get.

Comment: with current code, the error it throws is "'options must be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)"

Comment: if I change the code to  total$Order_Date<-as.Date(total$Order_Date,format = "%m/%d/%Y"),filter(total$Order_Date>= as.Date(input$date[1]) & total$Order_Date<= as.Date(input$date[2])) ,it thorws "Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
[31mx[39m Input `..1` must be of size 19 or 1, not size 756.
[34mi[39m Input `..1` is `&...`."

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are passing two dataframes to `plot_ly`, on the one hand you are passing `total %>% count(State, wt = sales)` to `plot_ly` and at the same time you pass `re_filt` to `plot_ly` via the `data` argument.

When fixing this your code runs fine. Try this:

```
output$state <- renderPlotly({
    total$Order_Date<- mdy(total$Order_Date)

    re_filt <- filter(total,
                      between(total$Order_Date,
                              as.Date(input$date[1]) ,
                              as.Date(input$date[2])))
    
    re_filt %>%
      count(State, wt = sales) %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~State, y = ~n, source = "State") %>%
      axis_titles() %>% 
      layout(title = "State")
  })
```

[image]